# Why am I getting this Error message- (Type Error- 'type' not subscriptable) and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, list, indexing, types

I am practicing list and string methods. In the if statement I am trying to make a letter upper case however, I am getting type error not subscriptable. Thanks for your help!

```
a = "Halloween"
a_list = list(a)
print("1.", a_list)

a_list[3] = a_list[3].upper()
print("2. ",a_list)

a_list[0] = a_list[0].lower()
print("3. ", a_list)

aword = "".join(a_list)
print("3.", aword)

asentence= "Happy Monday Python class"
asent_list = asentence.split()
print(asent_list)

for i in range (len(a_list)):
  if a-list[i] == "":
    a_list[i + 1] = a_list[i + 1].upper()
print(a_list)
```

Comment: Assuming this is Python code, I added its language tag.

Comment: Also please [edit] your question to include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste (as text!) of the output when running your program. It should include the `print` output as well as the error message.

Comment: `a-list[i]` is not the same thing as `a_list[i]`

Comment: As @jasonharper noted, you have a typo in your `for i in range...` loop at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've made a typo. `a-list[i]` should be `a_list[i]`.

Comment: Thanks everyone helping me learn Python!